# removing specific row in csv file, python

Tags: python, csv

I woud like to remove (delete) specific rows in csv file. But there are some conditions.

```
1.) File can't be buffered in memmory, becuse of it's size (1GB+)
2.) File MUST NOT be "touched" (rewriting file)
```

My job is just to delete some rows in csv file, without changing any other rows - Very important, becuse of encoding and sending filtered csv file to company which prints that files.

Is there solution?

Thank you!

Comment: why don't use a database?

Comment: can you make a new file and then not touch the old file?

Comment: i can make a new file, but i must delete some rows from old file, and filtered file then send ahead. Problem is, becuse i MUSTN'T rewrite rows which will stay becuse of problems with encoding

Comment: so you have to send the old file, that is modified? or can you send the new file?

Answer (score 2):

It can't be done. You want to delete content from a file, without modifying it. Those are mutually exclusive.

Comment: tell that to OP's boss ;)

Comment: What's his number, I'd be happy to give him a call ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the mmap interface to replace the row bytes by space characters.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an old timestamp using 'touch -t'. See the man page of 'touch' for more details.

```
touch -t 200510071138 old.dat
```

Just make sure you write down the original timestamp!

In order to remove the rows, you can use 'grep -v', which prints everything except your search terms.

```
grep -v baddata old.dat > new.dat
```

To modify with python, we're going to need some specific details of the file.